# Getting null pointer exception when trying to view database on web app

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to run the tutorial from this page, but whenever I click on  "Product List" or "Login" instead of getting the results from the database, I'm getting a null pointer exception and I can't figure out why.
https://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc#a812054

I created the database, created the tables and was able to connect to it in eclipse, so I'm pretty sure I've got the connection details right.

Database connected here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UscWn.png

Tables created here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTpYV.png

In the OracleConnUtils.java file I have substituted the following:

```
   String hostName = "localhost";
   String sid = "xe";
   String userName = "gpauser";
   String password = "<password>";
```

But when I run the application on the Tomcat server, I can see the home page and the log in page, but when I click "Product List" or actually try and login I get the below error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.o7planning.simplewebapp.utils.DBUtils.queryProduct(DBUtils.java:62)
>     org.o7planning.simplewebapp.servlet.ProductListServlet.doGet(ProductListServlet.java:35)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     org.o7planning.simplewebapp.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:42)
>     org.o7planning.simplewebapp.filter.CookieFilter.doFilter(CookieFilter.java:68)

Comment: Check `JdbcFilter`.

Comment: HI, I have JdbcFilter the same as in the tutorial, and I didn't see anything to update as per a DB connection. Am I missing something? I'm very new to databases...

Comment: See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)